# AspectJ getParameter()

Tags: eclipse, java-ee-6, aspectj

I want to become "" instead of null after getting parameter from Request variable.

```java
import javax.servlet.ServletRequest;

public aspect GetParameter {

    pointcut getParam(ServletRequest req, String s):
        target(req) && args(s) &&
        execution(String javax.servlet.ServletRequest.getParameter(String));

    String around(ServletRequest req, String s): getParam(req, s) { 
        String result = req.getParameter(s);
        if (result == null) {
            return "";
        }
        return result;    
}
```

in line `String around(ServletRequest req, String s): getParam(req, s) {` Eclipse show this mesage : advice defined in aspects.GetParameterOrAttribute has not been applied 
 [Xlint:adviceDidNotMatch]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

change execution to call, and ServletRequest to ServletRequest+. that should capture all the calls to getParameter on ServletRequest and its subclasses.